# ::before element not overlapping whole screen (not responsive)

Tags: html

Hey I have `::before` element on my page, but I found it's not responsive on higher resolution.

This is what it looks like:
[image: This is what it looks like:]

And my code of `::before`

```
#tmoc::before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
height: 54px;
background: transparent url(../img/ocean/back1.png) no-repeat scroll       1px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: -53px;
padding: 73px 0 0 0;
bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: a few things,  try removing one :    so it reads like this :  #tmoc:before   and your enforcing a height of 54px,  try removing the fixed height and using a percentage, then wrap the whole thing in a media query based on breakpoints.

Comment: Not working :/.

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 `::before` is correct, `:before` is deprecated.

Comment: Please create a reproducible, runnable snippet based on your code that demonstrates the problem. Pixels are pixels, no matter the screen resolution.

Comment: @connexo  you may be correct, i was basing the syntax off of mozilla's documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 Mozilla also has the correct `::before`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before . `:before` is CSS2, `::before` is CSS3.

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 That is exactly the reason CSS3 introduced the double colon. It separates *:pseudo classes* (like `:hover`, `:checked`, `:disabled` etc.)  from *::pseudo elements* (like `::before`, `::after`, `::first-line`, `::selection` etc.) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest answer I can come up without changing what you already have would be this: 
Use the photo editor of your choice (like Photoshop) or an online tiling website (like [imgonline](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/check-texture-tiling.php))and make the left and right edge of the image you are using exactly the same. This will allow you to repeat the image without getting any lines or weird breaks in the image. then change:

```
background: transparent url(../img/ocean/back1.png) no-repeat scroll 1px;
```

to:

```
background: transparent url(../img/ocean/back1.png) repeat-x scroll 1px;
```

I hope this helps